# If you download someone's repository, are they notified?

Tags: gitlab

On gitlab, if you navigate to a public repository, there is a download icon. Clicking this gives you the options to download as a zip, tar, etc.

If you download this, is the original owner notified, made aware? Through an email or a notification of that sort?

Just curious, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are no download statistics available for gitlab.

> ***Patricio Cano*** @patricio commented a year ago
>
> "I'm sorry, but we don't provide download statistics for files uploaded
>   to GitLab.com"

↳ https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/121

Comment: So they aren't notified on gitlab.

Do you know about github? I searched and it seems like they release download info.  But this means the author has to go and actively check if his repository has been downloaded. It's not like they receive a notification or email, correct?

Comment: Hmmm, from what I can tell there's nothing to indicate when/how/if anything was downloaded from a repo; where are you seeing the mention about releasing download info? Github on the other hand [has an API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) that allows you to know such things (eg. [`download_count`](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-the-download-count-for-your-releases/)).